# How to compile spec_cpu2006 with self-defined IR in LLVM?

Tags: llvm, benchmarking, llvm-ir

I have written an IR for tracking object address, now I need to **compile spec_cpu2006 with my IR**.

My running script for compiling general c++ code as follows：

Some variables

```
source_file = source + '.cpp'
obj = source + '.llvm'
opt_obj = source + '-opt.llvm'
executable = source + '-instrumented'
```

Running script

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -static -g -S  -emit-llvm -o obj source_file

opt -disable-inlining -S -load=full_trace.so -fulltrace  obj  -o opt_obj

llvm-link -o full.llvm  opt_obj + profile-func/trace_logger.llvm

llc -O0 -disable-fp-elim -filetype=asm -o full.s full.llvm

g++ -static -O0 -fno-inline -o ' + executable + ' full.s -lm -lz

./executable
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Which part of your script doesn't work?  Are you asking how to modify the Makefile for spec_cpu2006 to use your custom compile commands?

Comment: Yes,  I just want to konw how to modify the Makefile for spec_cpu2006, so that I can use   runspec.